# what is the most optimize makefile rules to a create an object needing a lot of intermidate and (mostly) useless files

Tags: makefile

I have some prerequisites: A, B, and C
And want to build F (final)

I can write the make rules (`create` and `update` are different for each command)

```
F : A B C
    create A1 from A 
    create A2 from A1
    create A3 from A2
    create B1 from B
    create F from C
    update F with B1
    update F with A3
```

or

```
F : C B1 A3
    create F from C
    update F with B1
    update F with A3        
B1 : B
    create B1 from B
A3 : A2
    create A3 from A2
A2 : A1
    create A2 from A1
A1 : A
    create A1 from A
```

Any idea what is the most reliable, fast ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More granularity in the Makefile is desirable. If one of the jobs in the pipeline fails, you can correct the error and pick up where make died. Additionally, the rules are easier to read.

The form with a single rule and many commands is slightly faster in execution because fewer timestamps will be checked and fewer rules need to be evaluated; however, the time difference is inconsequential.